# pre post condition on javascript?

Tags: javascript, state

I have a single timer button which showing `start` and `stop`. When I click it, the text changed to `stop`, and when I click it again then the text changed to `start`. To maintain the state, then I wrote a code like this:

```
start.onclick = function() {
    if (state == 0) {
        state = 1;
        timer();
    }
    if (state == 1) {
        state = 0;
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
}
```

Pre-condition of state is 0. On normal case, it should work if state equals 0, then state will changed to 1 and timer() will be executed. If state equals 1, state will changed to 0 and clearTimeout() will be executed. But I don't know why it won't work like this in javascript. Then I change the code like this:

```
start.onclick = function() {
    if (state == 0) {
        timer();
    }
    if (state == 1) {
        state = 0;
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
    state = 1;
}
```

Then it worked, timer() is executed and state changed to 1, but when I tried again to start the button, then nothing worked. I check the state, then the state is in 1. because the second condition is not executed. is anyone know what wrong with this code? what am I missing?

Comment: use `else if`, instead of 2 ifs

Comment: @JonasWilms. I assume, `t` is the timer set inside `timer()`

Comment: add "state=1" in "if(state==0)"

Comment: yups, t is timer inside the timer()

Comment: create variable "state" on global level for default value & use onclick func to change value

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets the `state` to 1, if it was 0.

This makes the condition in second `if` true, hence its code is also executed. Hence both ifs are executed when `state` is 0.

Use `else if` like

```
start.onclick = function () {
    if (state == 0) {
        state = 1;
        timer();
    } else if (state == 1) { <=== see the difference in this line
        state = 0;
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
}
```